# high concurrency database application

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, transactions, isolation-level, sqlclient

I created a window-based application (C#) that connects to SQL Server (using SQL client). There are many users using this app at the same time.

I have a form/screen that display a parent-child tables. When user click "Save" on this screen, I start a transaction in Read Uncommitted mode (using `BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)`). I use this mode because I want another user can read these table while this transaction is running.

The problem i faced is, sometime this "child" table is big (>10.000 rows) then the above transaction is very slow to complete. At then time these two tables (parent-child) are locked and another user cannot access them.

What I want is that to allow another user access these table normally because actually they are working on another record ID so there is no conflict.

Can anyone help me please ?

Le

Comment: This seems like a good article: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Comment: Thank you, It is very useful.